# Matlab like debugging tool for Julia

Tags: julia

I am writing a big project in Julia at the moment and the only option that I found to debug this code is `Debug.jl`. It is sooo(!) overwhelming to debug this code without a debugger like the one MATLAB has.

Are there any such debugging tools? I could adopt them even if they are in alpha stage.

Anyone has timeline estimates as to when they are planned to appear?

Answer (score 3):

There is work in progress by Keno Fischer (one of the core Julia developers) on a debugger called [Gallium.jl](https://github.com/Keno/Gallium.jl).

This is a very complicated piece of work, due to the nature of Julia as a JIT-compiled language; for example, as one piece, it will include a C++ REPL! As I understand it, there are still some technical issues that prevent it being used, but it will hopefully be available for general consumption "soon".

See [this video](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiz5avNwf_JAhWD1CYKHfiMAw8QtwIIGjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DKv6TO_gm2yw&usg=AFQjCNE-KuLp9ou5AZw28Uh3TbVvbefPxA&sig2=ULvVCiWVdZ1s7LFrt4XMGg&bvm=bv.110151844,d.eWE) for a demo, and [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-dev/-LTsBVRv1dU) on the julia-dev mailing list for the latest news.

Comment: Are there any progress on this? Do you know whether there is a visual debugger now?

Comment: Yes there is, in the Juno IDE, JunoLab.org